These are not interesting posts for me
The new front page claims:

Interesting posts for you
Based on your viewing history and watched tags.

And then it shows a tonne of stuff (50+ posts) I have zero interest in, with zero matches of my watched tags. Out of that I found exactly 2 posts which I had interest in which also matched some of my tags.
Possible scenarios:

The text on the front page lies and there is actually no matching between users and content - this is simply the same old front page as before. If this is the case, please remove the misleading text.
There is a matching between users and content but it is completely and utterly broken. If this is the case, please remove the misleading text along with the this supposed matching feature, until it is fixed.


It's just incomplete: "Loosely based on your viewing history and watched tag". Or maybe it's the same "based on" as the Hollywood "based on a true story"

@VLAZ I find that very hard to believe. Before the re-make the site highlighted actually interesting posts in the flood of uninteresting stuff. And now it doesn't. That appears to be the only change afaik. If it ain't broken then lets break it...

I hope btw that for the "Based on your viewing history" part, the Posts we handle as Reviewers in the 'Staging Ground' are/will not (be) taken into account for that Algorithm... (As we come across a lot of "random" Tags in the 'SG', even encouraged to do so for the 'Variety Reviewer' Badge... I also sometimes add an Upvote for Posts I handle and approve in the 'SG', or even "follow for a while" on 'Main' once approved, to check how they go, and if I missed anything (MRE + Input Data + Log (needed or not) / correct Tags / etc) in the 'SG''. But I wouldn't be interested in those Tags.)

"this is simply the same old front page as before" already showed content based on the user's preferences or perceived interests.

Removing the misleading text (which presumably means replacing it with truthful text) is obviously not the right solution.  Otherwise mine would say "Frustratingly irrelevant posts to annoy you."  The only acceptable solution is to improve relevance.

As another possibility: they could leave the text as is but stop displaying questions below it.

My userscript (https://stackapps.com/q/10634/67095) changes that to "suggested posts for you" :)

The text is just a lie right now, the question selection algorithm is the exact same as before. As confirmed by Staff in this comment by Piper:

[Interesting posts for you] is actually using the same logic that the old homepage was using! No changes. [...]

And further elaborated on by SpencerG:

Correct, its not really accurate at this stage. Though, my understanding is that we are pretty close to completing that part.


Except it no longer visually highlights questions with my watched tags. So not the same, just worse.

It seems to me that the staff tends to constantly argue errors away. It is not the first time. This bug makes Stack Overflow literally unusable for question askers, because why should a responder suddenly have to search for questions they would be willing to answer? That's what tags are for: to filter relevant questions.
I'm surprised that, in times of AI, such a relaxed approach is being taken, especially since AI is already causing Stack Overflow to lose relevance.

@SebastianRedl Piper was referring to the logic used to decide which question to show being the same, not the UI/UX being the same.

I'm annoyed by this "Interesting posts for you" for you stuff. Nothing I see is "Interesting posts for me".
I simply don't understand how hard it can be to do this correct. I have 3 watched tags - Is it hard to show me things with my watched tag?
But I get posts with tags that I don't even know what's about.
Had this design been open for votes, I'm sure it would be a record down vote.
Step up...
Edit
To be fair... After scrolling approx. 25 question down with tags I never visited, there was actual one question matching my watched tags. Great work :-(

It's no longer the site it was; I am extremely disappointed

Record down vote indeed. One of the worst in the site’s history, actually.

"I simply don't understand how hard it can be to do this correct." Really? I think it's impossible to do this well because with all the mediocre to bad questions even the best system would maybe not show any questions at all. They can only work with what is there.

I've started just ignoring tags that aren't interesting to me. My home page now has 70/96 questions that are "relevant" (has one of my watched tags in it). Whether they are of "interest" to me is another question, but it's a step up.


And yes.. I'd rather add 100 tags to my ignore list than have to go through 4 clicks to filter by my watched tags.

I still have a lot of irrelevant questions, and I can’t even add more tags :/
