With the new homepage UX it’s impossible to add more ignored tags when you already have a lot of them
The new homepage is very frustrating for the ignored tags: right now the top question on my homepage is about "micronaut", something I don’t know anything about, so I want to ignore the tag but if I hover or click on it I’m only offered to watch it (no!).
Furthermore, the list of ignored tags is very hard to find: you have to click on the cog at the top-right of the "Watched tags" block (ignoring the overlay that says "Watch more tags"), then click on "Ignored tags" at the top of the popin. Even then, you only see the beginning of the list and can’t scroll down to add more:

If you zoom in, the design is confusing: there are more tags to see (but you can’t scroll!), and at the same time you see the "bottom" of the popin with the rounded corners:

The only way I found to circumvent the new useless homepage header is to click on a random tag to go to a page with the previous list layout that shows the ignored tags on the right:

By the way, the new homepage header is totally useless for me and yet it takes ~30% of my vertical screen space when I open the page.

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/432223/735926

For sure it's borked. It kind of all breaks down with the fact that the homepage does not yet make better suggestions, it's still as random and pointless as it ever was. If they had fixed that BEFORE making all these iterative UI changes... you wouldn't have needed the giant list of ignored tags, hopefully.

Suggestion: "You can't ignore more than 5 tags" message.

@Sinatr "To ignore more than 5 tags, purchase Stack Overflow Gold®™ subscription"

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/432107/735926

Here's the CSS I use to fix it:
.tags-list {
    max-height: 60vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}


It would also be nice to add the hover > ignore tag button onto the homepage that already exists on the Meta Homepage.


"It would also be nice to add the hover > ignore tag button onto the homepage that already exists on the Meta Homepage." it exists everywhere except on SO. It was explicitly removed. As was the ignore button on the tag page. Explanation for that one is pending.
